# What is the use of PlottableValue label in Swift Charts?

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts

In the following two charts, labels(Category and Value) are reversed. But they are drawn in the same way.

Then what is the use of label in PlottableValue?

```swift
Chart {
    BarMark(
        x: .value("Category", "Label"),
        y: .value("Value", 100)
    )
}
```

```swift
Chart {
    BarMark(
        x: .value("Value", "Label"),
        y: .value("Category", 100)
    )
}
```